# Submitting form from input[type=file] dialog box

Tags: jquery, wp-filesystem

I am attempting to trigger a form submit from an input [type=file] dialog box window. I realize this might be a bit substandard, but here's what I'm trying to do.

1. User clicks the browse button, and input[type=file] dialog window is invoked letting the user select a file.
2. After the user selects file and when the open button is pressed in the same window, the file dialog box (in addition to whatever else it does), submits the specified form (jQuery perhaps?) with the selected image.

This actually works quite well for the media library window using the following code:

```
wp.media.wpUserAvatar.frame().state('library').on('select', function() {
        jQuery("[class='name-of-form'] input[type='submit']").click();
    });
```

So I'm hoping there's an equivalent for the standard file input window.

thanks!

Comment: What is the “the standard wp_filesystem window”? As far as I know, there’s no such thing. Are you sure you’re not just thinking of a standard `<input type="file">` element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have updated the question to hopefully make it more clear. :)